How to set widget above of center widget in flutter?
I have one constraint widget in center of screen so i want to add new widget which is above of center widget.
I have added red box in center of the screen and i want to place blue box above of red box.

I have tried with constraint and column widget in stack widget but new widget not set on above of center widget.
body: Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 150,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),


To place a widget above the center widget, you can use the Stack widget to layer your widgets. Here’s a simple example based on your code:
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

Example


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Stateful Clicker Counter';
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Click Counter'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I Hope this may help you
